# how to pass input element into h3 tag not in url

Tags: javascript

I want to update h3 tag every time user clicks but it does not update it updates the tab url but i do not want to update URL, I wanted to update only h3 tag.

```
I attached all files and URL screenshot.
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
            <h3 id="url">https://localhost:8080/</h3>
            <label for="name">Name :</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
            <label for="year">Graduation Year :</label><br>
            <input type="number" id="year" name="year"><br>
            <button id="button" onclick="updateURL()">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

here javaScript code.

```
const name = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
const year = document.getElementById("year").innerHTML;
let url = document.getElementById("url");
const oldURL = url.innerHTML;
const newURL = oldURL + "?name=" + name + "&year=" + year;

function updateURL() {
    
    url.innerHTML = newURL;
}
console.log("hiii");
console.log(oldURL)
console.log(newURL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add `type="button"` inside your `<button>` declaration, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10836076/18099076).

Then, you need `.value` of your HTML elements, and their declaration must be inside your function, otherwise they will be executed as the page loads, and will be empty.

```js
function updateURL(e) {
const name = document.getElementById("name").value;
const year = document.getElementById("year").value;
console.log(name, year);
let url = document.getElementById("url");
const oldURL = url.innerHTML;
const newURL = oldURL + "?name=" + name + "&year=" + year;
    url.innerHTML = newURL;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <h3 id="url">https://localhost:8080/</h3>
            <label for="name">Name :</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
            <label for="year">Graduation Year :</label><br>
            <input type="number" id="year" name="year"><br>
            <button type="button" id="button" onclick="updateURL()">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```